# What is the purpose of the sharpie marks on some Pis

Tags: pi-zero-w

I recently obtained a Pi Zero W and there was what looks to be a sharpie mark besides the trapezoidal antenna beneath the Broadcom chip and besides the micro usb port. I subsequently went on google images and noticed that a number Pi Zero W boards also sport this marking. Out of curiosity, does anyone happen to know the reason behind these markings? Are they perhaps used during quality control testing to denote that a board has passed inspections?

Comment: What do you mean by "sharpie"?  Do you mean the green triangle thing? ( https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w ), (https://www.briandorey.com/post/raspberry-pi-zero-w-external-antenna-mod )

Comment: `sharpie` is a brand name for a felt tipped marker ... https://www.sharpie.com/

Comment: @jsotola, Thanks a lot.  So I should look for a "Sharpie mark" beside the trapezoidal antenna.  But I did not see any marking by a Sharpie felt pen.  And the "triangle" thing I saw should be the "trapezoidal".  BTW, I never heard of "Sharpie".  I only know the classy Japan "Zebra" and "Pilot" ball/felt pens.  I also know the ugly looking BiC ball pen.

Comment: Oh right. I was referring to permanent markers. In the States they're commonly referred to as Sharpies, since that's the most common brand.